# Determine which face was clicked in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, faces

How might one go about determining which face of a model was clicked on a mouse up event inside BGE? For example, I have a map model with several selectable locations. Each location consists of at least one face (some more). I need to know which face was selected after user clicks mouse, to know which location to send a character model.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think  the normal is a face in [rayCast](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=ray%20cast#bge.types.KX_GameObject.rayCast) return the hit object, point and normal.

Comment: You could also combine a "mouse over" with a "mouse click" sensor then send a message to the character, containing the selected location

Comment: @Quacksilber Yes, this is the gist of what I'm trying to do, but how can I obtain the face (normal) that was clicked? In bge after the mouse click event, how do I know which normal was clicked?

Comment: Depends on the number and size of these areas. Maybe you could post a picture of your map, with locations? My Approach would be to make individual objects , set to invisible, that each cover a location; but as I said this method only makes sense if your map isnt too big :)

Comment: @Quacksilber !! That's actually what I'm doing right now! :) I was just trying to come up with a way to not have to create individual collision objects for each location. One thing I was thinking was having an array that contained the vertex positions of each location, then on mouse click do a raycast and see if the click position turns up in any of those points. Then if so, I could change the material color of those normals and move the character to the center location. Does that sound feasible or overly complex? lol